# Process hierarchy and name registration

Tags: erlang

Let’s say, I have one or more robot turtles each with a left and a right wheel, an encoder on both the left and right wheel. The wheels might have a PID controlled motor. In a system like ROS, one would have access to the systems and subsystems through a hierarchical naming system: i.e. /turtle_1/lwheel/pid/kp to set the Kp parameter of the left wheel’s PID controller or /turtle_3/lwheel/encoder to fetch the wheel’s encoder reading.  The turtles would be nodes on a LAN.

Since Erlang has a flat name space for registering processes, how should one implement such a hierarchical view?  I guess one could have a registered process for each level in the hierarchy with as its name the full qualified name of the subsystem as in (/turtle_1 for the top process, /turtle_1/lwheel for the process that controls the wheels , /turtle_1/lwheel_1/pid etc.
Is there some best practice for maintaining a hierarchical view using the global module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to solve this is to introduce a routing process or a routing map which can bind a hierarchy to a `Pid`. You have several options:

- `gproc` provides nice ETS based registry tables
- A process implementing the hierarchy with eventual forwarding on the LAN
- Global - it takes arbitrary terms as a name, so one could register a tuple in the namespace which would amount to having a tree-ordered namespace.
- A process updating an ETS table so the routing decision itself is in the message sender.

What is best depends on your need for consensus in the distributed setting and/or on the speed you need for a routing lookup. Also, on wether or not you can cache Routing lookups.

Comment: Do you rather cache pid lookups when you are using gproc or you fecth the pid for every gen_xxxx call ?

Comment: I rarely cache them. Lookup is a few microseconds usually. There are so many other things which will have a much higher price in a setup.

Comment: Thanks. I do this too, the module API exports functions which are passed an ID and each function lookups the Pid so pass to gen_server:call or other "gen calls" ; but i didn't know if it was OK. Seems to :)

Comment: gproc seems to be overkill for what I am trying to do. Also, since I am new to Erlang, I prefer to stick to the core modules. So, I had a look at 'global' but there are not much code examples to be found on the subject. It seems I have to connect each spawned process with a net_adm:ping to another node to make it work. Any suggestions on not having to connect over and over again?

Comment: gproc can do much things but i found it very lightweight. You should give it a try